# Enable hydroelastic for box geometry

Tags: drake

I'm able to make a sphere geometry hydroelastic using the following code:

```
# Add sphere geometry
pusher_geometry = Sphere(dimensions)
pusher_shape = AddShape(
    plant,
    pusher_geometry,
    "pusher_geometry",
    color=[0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0],
)
_ = plant.AddRigidBody(
    "false_body1", pusher_shape, SpatialInertia(0, [0, 0, 0], UnitInertia(0, 0, 0))
)
pusher_geometry_x = plant.AddJoint(
    PrismaticJoint(
        "pusher_geometry_x",
        plant.world_frame(),
        plant.GetFrameByName("false_body1"),
        [1, 0, 0],
        -10.0,
        10.0,
    )
)
pusher_geometry_x.set_default_translation(position[0])
plant.AddJointActuator("pusher_geometry_x", pusher_geometry_x)
_ = plant.AddRigidBody(
    "false_body2", pusher_shape, SpatialInertia(0, [0, 0, 0], UnitInertia(0, 0, 0))
)
pusher_geometry_y = plant.AddJoint(
    PrismaticJoint(
        "pusher_geometry_y",
        plant.GetFrameByName("false_body1"),
        plant.GetFrameByName("false_body2"),
        [0, 1, 0],
        -10.0,
        10.0,
    )
)
pusher_geometry_y.set_default_translation(position[1])
plant.AddJointActuator("pusher_geometry_y", pusher_geometry_y)
pusher_geometry_z = plant.AddJoint(
    PrismaticJoint(
        "pusher_geometry_z",
        plant.GetFrameByName("false_body2"),
        plant.GetFrameByName("pusher_geometry"),
        [0, 0, 1],
        -10.0,
        10.0,
    )
)
pusher_geometry_z.set_default_translation(position[2])
plant.AddJointActuator("pusher_geometry_z", pusher_geometry_z)

# Make pusher_geometry complient hydroelastic
    pusher_geometry = plant.GetBodyByName("pusher_geometry")
    geometry_ids = plant.GetCollisionGeometriesForBody(pusher_geometry)
    inspector = scene_graph.model_inspector()
    for geometry_id in geometry_ids:
        new_proximity_properties = ProximityProperties()
        AddCompliantHydroelasticProperties(
            resolution_hint=0.1,
            hydroelastic_modulus=1e8,
            properties=new_proximity_properties,
        )
        const_proximity_properties = inspector.GetProximityProperties(geometry_id)
        copy_object_proximity_properties(
            const_proximity_properties, new_proximity_properties
        )
        scene_graph.AssignRole(
            plant.get_source_id(),
            geometry_id,
            new_proximity_properties,
            RoleAssign.kReplace,
        )
```

However, this no longer works when I replace `pusher_geometry = Sphere(dimensions)` with `pusher_geometry = Box(dimensions[0], dimensions[1], dimensions[2])`. For the sphere, `geometry_ids` contains a single ID, while for the box, it contains multiple IDs. The system breaks with "RuntimeError: Bad tetrahedron. Cannot compute gradient.", the second time that `scene_graph.AssignRole` is called. It works when I apply the property to the first geometry ID rather than to all of them but doesn't work if I assign it to a random one. I don't know how to differentiate the geometries associated with the different geometry IDs. They all seem to have the same properties.

Why are there multiple geometry IDs for a box, and what do these different IDs refer to? How do I know which of these geometry IDs to assign the hydroelastic properties to?

Comment: The exception you get indicate the shape provided is degenerate (close to zero volume). What are the values for `dimensions`? Also, the constructor of Sphere takes a single scalar for its radius, so `Sphere(dimensions)` is a little suspicious.

Providing the definition for your `AddShape` function might be helpful for diagnosing why multiple geometries are added.

Comment: `dimensions` is a scalar in this case. Sorry for the horrible naming.

`AddShape` is from the manipulation repo (see https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/master/manipulation/scenarios.py#L199). But looking at that code, it now makes sense why there are multiple collision geometries; the code adds contact spheres.
Checking the simulation logic, the code seems to work if I add the hydroelastic properties to the main body but breaks when I add it to the contact spheres. These spheres are indeed close to zero volume due to their tiny radius.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to obtain the geometry volume from a geometry ID? That way it would be possible to differentiate between the box body and the contact spheres.

Comment: Without looking at `AddShape()`, I'm going to bet that it adds tiny contact spheres on the corners. For hydroelastic, you don't need those extra spheres.

As for computing geometry volume, there is [CalcVolume()](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html?highlight=calcvolume#pydrake.geometry.CalcVolume). It doesn't take `GeometryId`, but you can get the `Shape` from [SceneGraphInspector::GetShape()](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html?highlight=scenegraphinspector#pydrake.geometry.SceneGraphInspector.GetShape).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AddShape()` function when invoked with a Box geometry adds tiny spheres (radius 1e-7 meter) to the corners of the box. That explains

1. more than one collision geometry when you use boxes, and
2. the runtime error which is caused by trying to tetrahedralize the tiny spheres.

Instead of calling `AddShape()`, I'd recommend directly add the box collision geometry via `plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(...)` and the box visual geometry via `plant.RegisterVisualGeometry(...)`.

If you prefer checking the volume, you can use `SceneGraphInspector::GetShape` which takes a GeometryId to get the shape and find the volume of the shape with `CalcVolume(shape)`. However, doing that leaves the tiny spheres in your simulation, which participates in contact using point contact and defeats the purpose of hydroelastics.